# What does the PDF of a CDF² mean?

Tags: probability-distributions, data-analysis

I have empirical data representing a CDF. I fitted a normal/gaussian CDF (the line) to it, call it *F*(x)

[image]

I have found that squaring the data points gives a better fit; *F*(x)² = P(X ≤ x)²:

[image]

And here's their corresponding PDFs:

[image]

[Link to desmos with all of this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r51uscdwcq)

I understand what the purple PDF is, i.e. P(X = x), for a loosely fitted curve. **But what does the green PDF represent?**

My thoughts: Since a PDF is the derivative of a CDF, and the derivative of *F*(x)² = 2 *F*(x), the green curve could be 2P(X = x). But that would mean the area under its curve would have to add up to 2, and it clearly equals 1.

Comment: Errr no, the derivative of $[F(x)]^2$ is $2F(x)f(x)$. Remember the chain rule for differentiation from Calculus 101?

Comment: If your model does not have theoretical justification, you can revise your model to reflect what you have found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables with the same CDF $F(x)$, then
$$P(\max(X,Y) \leq \alpha) = P(X \leq \alpha, Y \leq \alpha) = P(X\leq \alpha)P(Y \leq \alpha) = [F(x)]^2.$$
Thus, $ [F(x)]^2$ is the CDF of the maximum of two independent random variables with the same CDF $F(x)$. How this notion can be fitted into your model remains to be seen.